# firebase python prevent auto id generation when post

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

How can I prevent auto id generation when python post?

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com', None)
path = '/mypath'
data = {'href': 'value'}
result = firebase.post(path, data)
print result
```

Then I get like
/mypath/-KVuKSh7Ih7LXdAgGY0a/href : value
instead of
/mypath/href : value

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com',  None)
path = '/mypath'
data = {'href': 'value'}
result = firebase.put(path,'',data)
print result
```